# Automatic increment for new items in asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview

I have a database where there are two levels of information. Level A is the parent level where item are named as X00001, X00002, X00003 .. etc.

The second level is the child of the first level so the naming is like the following, X000010001, X000010002, X000010003 ... - These three belongs to the first item in the Level A, X000020001, X000020002, X000020003 ...These belong to the second item and so on.

I have a gridview setup in ASP. When the user creates a new item they select the item name from level 1 through a dropdown, such as X00001. What I want is it should automatically be named in the second level by incrementing the last item in the group.

For example, if the user selects X00001 and it has three items (X000010001, X000010002, X000010003), the new item should automatically be named as X000010004.

The tables are hosted in an SQL server.

Comment: Because you have an alphanumeric field you will need to split your string into sections, increment the last segment and then put it together into a string before inserting it into your db table.

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is it should detect how many items in each group is and increment based on the last number in each group.

Comment: In that case upon select run a wildcard query, e.g. SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID LIKE 'X00001%'. This will give you all the records in the selected group.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like we're getting somewhere, I'll get back to you after testing it.

Comment: I ran a test on the wildcard query, it works great. Now I need some help in incrementing items in every group

Comment: Maybe you can email me later and we can chat.